# How to make Selenium WebDriverWait Wait for text in unspecified location on page

Tags: selenium, text, webdriverwait

How to make Selenium WebDriverWait Wait for text in unspecified location

When the page updates the new text appears. I want a way of searching for that text, but I am unable to do do that. Trying to search by ID use useless because I can only view the stale HTML in chrome. I am proper stuck I tell thee!

Comment: Are unailable to find the XPATH? Or that it doesn't have one?

Comment: The question isn't understood...

Comment: I somehow doubt the updated text appears in some random location. Surely you know where it's going to end up. Just search for it there. Post a link to the page and we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If your expected text has no ancered location...

You can just use the `contains` function of XPATH...

For instance:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains (text(), 'your expected text')]")))
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: The problem is that that approach is going to find *every* parent that contains that text. That might be one or two elements or it could be half the elements on the page depending on the way the page is constructed.

Comment: @JeffC Given that the text he is expecting is unique and has no other way to locate I think this is a good aproch... Yet the question is not so clear so we won't know until he edits it or responds to us...